# How to display data in Edit view in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS. I am working on a website which uses ASP.Net MVC and AngularJS. The site offers basic functionality Add/Update/Delete/Retrieve. I am using angular routing to navigate through the site. The routing code is given below:

```
var app = angular.module("paymentApp", ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "payment/EditPayment/1",
            controller: "paymentController"
        })
        .when("/MakePayment", {
            templateUrl: "payment/MakePayment",
            controller: "paymentController"
        })
        .when("/SearchPayment", {
            templateUrl: "payment/SearchPayment",
            controller: "paymentController"
        })
        .when("/EditPayment/:payid", {
            templateUrl: function (params) { return "payment/EditPayment/" + params.payid },
            controller: "paymentController"
        })
        .when("/DeletePayment/:id", {
            templateUrl: function (params) { return "payment/DeletePayment/" + params.id },
            controller: "paymentController"
        })
        .when("/Flush", {
            templateUrl: "payment/InvalidateCacheForIndexAction",
            controller: "paymentController"
        });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('');
});
```

You can figure out from the above given code that I am calling MVC action methods to display MakePayment/SearchPayment views that do not have any pre-populated data to display as the user needs to enter the data in those views. However the EditPayment view is going to have the data of the payment made earlier. My routing code is simply going to pull the EditPayment view with no values. I am not sure what is the correct approach to display the existing data in that view.

My EditPayment.cshtm code is given below:

```
<h2>Edit Payment</h2>

<div ng-controller="paymentController" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <section id="paymentForm">
            <form class="form-horizontal">

                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <h4>Edit payment</h4>
                <hr />
                <span class="text-danger" ng-show="false">Validation error summary</span>
                <div ng-show="confCode">
                    <label style="background-color:darkseagreen;">Payment has been made successfully. Confirmation code: {{confCode}}</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Payment Id</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="paymentId" readonly />
                        <span class="text-danger" ng-show="false">Payment Id required</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Biller Id</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10" name="BillerId" id="BillerId">
                        <select class="form-control" ng-model="billerId" ng-init="billerId='0'">
                            <option disabled hidden value="0">Select biller</option>
                            <option value="1">Idea</option>
                            <option value="2">Airtel</option>
                            <option value="3">Vodafone</option>
                            <option value="4">Jio</option>
                        </select>
                        <span class="text-danger" ng-show="false">Biller Id required</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Bill Account</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="billAccount" />
                        <span class="text-danger" ng-show="false">Bill account required</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Payment amount</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="paymentAmount" />
                        <span class="text-danger" ng-show="false">Payment amount required</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Fee amount</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="feeAmount" value="1.0" readonly />
                        <span class="text-danger" ng-show="false">Fee amount required</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Platform</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="platform" value="1.0" readonly />
                        <span class="text-danger" ng-show="false">Platform required</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Pay" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="makePayment()" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

My paymentController.js looks like:

```
app.controller("paymentController", function ($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, paymentService) {    
    $scope.paymentId;
    $scope.billerId;
    $scope.billAccount;
    $scope.paymentAmount;
    $scope.feeAmount=1.0;
    $scope.platform = 1;
    $scope.confCode;
    $scope.makePayment = function () {
        var payment = {
            BillerId: $scope.billerId,
            BillAccount: $scope.billAccount,
            PayAmt: $scope.paymentAmount,
            FeeAmt: $scope.feeAmount,
            Platform: $scope.platform,
        };
        paymentService.makePayment(payment).then(function (response) {
            $scope.confCode = response.data.ConfCode;
        });
    };

    $scope.searchPayment = function () {        
        var searchPay = {
            BillerId: $scope.billerId,
            BillAccount: $scope.billAccount
        };
        paymentService.searchPayment(searchPay).then(function (response) {
            $scope.payments = response.data;            
        });
    };
});
```

Also, I am using same controller for Add/Update/Edit/Delete. Is it the correct approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, saying whether using same controller for Add/Update/Edit/Delete is a good/bad approach is mostly a matter of perspective; in my opinion, it's not the best way to do this when you're planning to do a big system, or at least you plan to scale your app to a larger one. It becomes messy and non-productive since many functionalities are together even when they differ a lot sometimes. This should be evaluated in your particular case and find a balance between reuse code and make things clear and separated, always looking for a neat, clean and reusable code.

About how to populate your edit view, you just have to get the `payid` from the route and use it for retrieving the info from the backend.

The sequence should go like this:

- User click edit payment, (you add the `payid` to the route)
- You load the *EditPayment* view (so this intatiates the `paymentController`)
- At the moment of loading the `paymentController` you check for `payid` on the route like this: `$route.current.params.payid`
- If `$route.current.params.payid` exists, it means your view should load the data related to that payment (in order to get this data, you probably already made a service)
- Once your data is retrieved from the backend, you bind that to your view model.
- Done! On *EditPayment* should now be showing the data related to that specific payment.

Comment: Thanks for your expert solution! I just had another question. It'd be very helpful if you can answer it. If I hadn't used AngularJS there would have been only one call to the server(MVC action method call) but with AngularJS there would be two calls - first one will get the empty view and second call would pull the data. Is it not detrimental to performance?

Comment: The explanation could be too large for a comment, but we have to take into account the concept of SPA (take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application), which represents a different way in which we represent a web app to the users. The opposite to this approach is that all web pages are rendered by the server, as it was always done before SPA. Both ways are completely valid options, you just have to analyze which one fits better your needs according to the principles of each one.

Comment: In simple words, with SPA you render the web app once and load all partials view on demand, this can produce many asyn calls to backend services, yes,but html is rendered only once, most of the time, I prefer better this. If we do not use SPA the server have to return a page with data, this can be slower than just getting a json and printing data on the view(html). As I said before, you have to evaluate carefully what's what  you need(And I know sometimes is not easy).I just recommend you, search on internet, read, and learn always keeping in mind best pracitces. Noways there are many options.